# How do I deserialize this JSON string from API (array of arrays)

Tags: c#

Imagine the `serialized` variable was from an API and that I don't have the RsTarget class as the client of the API.

I was thinking I can deserialize it to a dynamic object and just access properties that way. However, having a little trouble understanding how to do this. It is an array of arrays. I found how to deserialize the top level array but the elements are in JSON strings.

Let's say I'd like to access Target3 property.

Am I looking at this all wrong? Should I duplicate the RsTarget on the client? What if the API changes the RsTarget?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<RsTarget>> toReturn = new List<List<RsTarget>>();

            List<RsTarget> list = new List<RsTarget>();
            list.Add(new RsTarget() { Id = 1, MyProperty = "Target1" });

            List<RsTarget> list2 = new List<RsTarget>();
            list2.Add(new RsTarget() { Id = 2, MyProperty = "Target2" });
            list2.Add(new RsTarget() { Id = 3, MyProperty = "Target3" });

            toReturn.Add(list);
            toReturn.Add(list2);

            var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toReturn);

            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(serialized).ToObject<List<List<JObject>>>();
        }
    }

    class RsTarget
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

that shouldn't be a problem when you get `JArray`

```
var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(serialized);
for(var i = 0;i < arr.Count; i++)
{
    JArray arr2 = arr[i] as JArray;

    for(var j = 0;j < arr2.Count; j++)
    {
        JObject obj = arr2[j] as JObject;
        // using dynamic 
        dynamic dobj = obj;
        var Id = (int)doObj.Id;
       // using strong type
       var strongObj = obj.ToObject<MyClientClass>()
    }
}
```

---

> Should I duplicate the RsTarget on the client? What if the API changes the RsTarget

The best way to duplicate the RsTarget on the client. and for your second question :  It alway break your app when api chages the property name even if you use `JObject` , but if only add a property, they both won't be effected.

Comment: I forgot your json is an array of an array , anyway you should understand how the JObject and JArray workd